# comparison of two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've two numpy 2d arrays (say A & B, sometime size equal or sometime not equal). I need to compare first column of both arrays and find the index of elements that occur in both arrays.

The below shown code gave me solution whenever the both arrays have different size and all elements of A are not present in B.

`C=np.squeeze(A[np.array(np.where(np.in1d(A[:,0],B[:,1]))).T],axis=None)`

But it is incorrect whenever  all elements of  A are present in B.

Can anyone suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

If A and B are the following:

```
A=np.random.randint(0,5,(10,8))
B=np.random.randint(3,7,(10,8))
>>> A
array([[4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4],
       [4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3],
       [3, 4, 3, 0, 3, 4, 2, 0],
       [4, 1, 3, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2],
       [4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2],
       [4, 1, 4, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2],
       [0, 1, 4, 0, 2, 2, 1, 4]])
>>> B
array([[4, 3, 5, 6, 4, 6, 3, 5],
       [6, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 4],
       [5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3],
       [3, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 3, 6],
       [5, 6, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3],
       [3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 6, 6, 3],
       [6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 3, 4, 6],
       [4, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 3, 3],
       [5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 6],
       [4, 3, 3, 6, 6, 4, 3, 4]])
```

You could use `intersect1d` to find the values that are in both

```
np.intersect1d(A,B)
array([3, 4])
```

And then `argwhere` to find the indices of the values in, for example, column 0 of `A`:

```
[np.argwhere(x==A[:,0]) for x in np.intersect1d(A,B)]
```

returns

```
[array([[3],
   [8]]), array([[0],
   [2],
   [4],
   [6],
   [7]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0],
       [4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
       [3, 4, 3, 0, 3, 4, 2],
       [4, 1, 3, 0, 1, 4, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3],
       [4, 1, 4, 0, 3, 1, 2],
       [3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4],
       [0, 1, 4, 0, 2, 2, 1]])

B=np.array([[4, 3, 5, 6, 4, 6, 3, 5],
       [6, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 4],
       [5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3],
       [3, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 3, 6],
       [5, 6, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3],
       [3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 6, 6, 3],
       [6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 3, 4, 6],
       [4, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 3, 3],
       [5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 6],
       [4, 3, 3, 6, 6, 4, 3, 4]])

matched = A.T[0][A.T[0] == B.T[0]]

>> [4,3,4]
```